# Simply entering the debugger during execution of MATLAB GUI fixes error that persists during normal execution

Tags: matlab, user-interface, debugging, focus

I'm using a programmatic GUI in MATLAB which uses multiple figure windows. When I press the button 'Redraw' in Figure A, a new figure appears (Figure B) with some data plotted. I want the focus to immediately switch back to Figure A because there are many hotkeys (WindowKeyPressFcn) that I use in that window to update the plots in Figure B.

There are two problems here:

1) The last line of the callback for the button 'Redraw' does switch focus back to Figure A, BUT only if Figure B exists already. That is, the first time Figure B is created, it remains in focus. If I then use Figure A to update the plots in Figure B, the focus correctly switches back to Figure A. I can't think of why it behaves differently during the first redraw and all subsequent calls.

2) The even bigger issue is that if I set a breakpoint anywhere in the code and then resume execution, the focus switches back to Figure A as I want. So, why does entering the debugger and doing nothing else fix the problem? How can I find the issue if everything works in the debugger?

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT:** To my great surprise, I was able to reproduce this "Heisenbug" by writing my first ever programmatic GUI. This should be the simplest example of my problem. To see it in action, simply run the code below and click on the push button. For some reason, when Window 2 is created for the first time, the focus does NOT switch back to Window 1 as intended. It works properly for all subsequent button presses. Try closing Window 2 and pushing the button again, the error will keep occurring.

As mentioned in the original post, setting a breakpoint in the code resolves the issue. Set a breakpoint at line 27, then resume execution and Window 1 will be in focus.

What is happening here?

```
 function heisenbug

%% Main problem:
% After clicking the push button, I want the focus to
% always switch back to Window 1 (the one containing the button).
% However, this does not work when Window 2 is first created.
%%

%% Create and then hide the GUI as it is being constructed
f = figure('Visible','off','name','Window 1','units','normalized','Position',[0.1 0.1 0.5 0.5]);

%% Initialize handles structure
handles = guihandles(f);
handles.window2 = [];
guidata(f,handles)

%% Make a button
hbutton = uicontrol('Style','pushbutton','String','Push me','units','normalized',...
    'Position',[0.1 0.1 0.8 0.8],...
    'Callback',@button_Callback);

%% Make the GUI visible
f.Visible = 'on';

%% Button callback
    function button_Callback(source,eventData)
        handles = guidata(gcbo);
        % If Window 2 already exists, plot a circle, then switch focus back to Window 1.
        if ~isempty(handles.window2) && ishandle(handles.window2)
            figure(handles.window2);
            plot(1,1,'bo')
            figure(f);
        % Otherwise, create Window 2 and do the same thing.
        else
            handles.window2 = figure('Name','Window 2','units','normalized','position',[0.4 0.1 0.5 0.5]);
            plot(1,1,'bo')
            figure(f)
        end
        guidata(source,handles)
    end

end
```

Comment: You've got a heisenbug: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heisenbug

Comment: Well that's fun, but naming the problem didn't make it go away :(

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: @excaza I appreciate the link and hope that my new edit will enable someone to help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My post was quickly answered by Adam (thanks!) on the MathWorks site: http://se.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/299607-simply-entering-the-debugger-during-execution-of-matlab-gui-fixes-error-that-persists-during-normal.

I needed to insert a `pause(0.05)` after Window 2 is created, before trying to switch the focus back with `figure(f)`. Otherwise the focus is stolen back to Window 2 when it finishes plotting.